# Tor and Google Analytics - how to track?

Tags: browser-detecting, vpn

I make a lot of use of Google Analytics - Google has reasonable tracking for location of users so I can tell where users come from. I know it is not 100% but it gives an idea.

In the wake of Prism it is possible that more people will make use of networks such as tor for anonymous browsing. I have no problem with this, people can wear tin foil hats while browsing my site for all I care, but it will lead to more erroneous stats.

Is there any way to flag traffic as coming from TOR, so I can filter location reports not to include it, and to get an idea of the percentage of traffic which does use it?

Has anyone actually tried this?

Answer (score 2):

[A comprehensive list](https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/) of Tor exit node IP addresses is already made public by the Tor project (remember that these addresses tend  to change over time).

Combine said IP addresses with Google Analytics' [filtering options](https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/1032939?hl=en&ref_topic=1726911) and I'm sure it can be done.

[This section](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq-abuse.html.en#Bans) of Tor's FAQ may also be useful to you, so might [TorDNSEL](https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en).